# React after updating an object's state with useState hook, I can't call any of its functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making a blackjack card counting training app for context.

It currently deals out cards and has a basic `hit` functionality, I ran into complexity when dealing with splits (too many nested arrays), so I figured I would make a `Players` and `Player` objects, but I'm running into issues when trying to update the state with the `useState` hook.

The main issue is I am clearly updating an objects state incorrectly using the `useState()` hook. My naïve assumption was if I have my `players` object with its internal state, and I call functions to update the state, and then do a simple `setPlayers(players)`, that would work. I've read online that because it's an object, you have to deep copy it so React recognizes it as a new object or something along those lines. When I do the above idea, my `useEffect()` hook reacting to `players` updating, never executes - so it isn't picking up on the object change. On the other side of things, my UI actually does update... which confuses me.

I have tried many different ways I have found online (there are many posts about this, but every solution gives me the same error that makes me feel I'm just not understanding something), but all to varying degrees of success. If I do

`setPlayers({...players})`

my `useEffect` hook executes unlike `setPlayers(player)`. The problem is in doing this, after calling `setPlayers({..players})`, I get the following error when, after dealing I try to hit for the 2nd time. I can deal, then hit once, then I get the following: `Uncaught TypeError: players.hit is not a function`. I found other solutions using a callback and I get the same error.

I made a `Players` and `Player` class (not a component) to deal with some of the hand logic. I ran into complexity dealing with splitting a blackjack hand, so I figured I'd abstract it out to a class. I am pretty sure using these classes with `useState()` is running me into problems. I have looked at other posts about updating an object so it re-renders, and they produce different behavior but none of which I really want...

So my `Players` and `Player` class are very stateful, many functions don't return a value, they just update their internal `hands` state.

Here's my `Players` and `Player` class.

```
class Players {
    constructor(numPlayers) {
        this.numPlayers = numPlayers;
        this.players = new Array(numPlayers).fill().map( () => (new Player()));
        this.currentPlayer = 0;
    }
    hit(card) {
        this.players[this.currentPlayer].hit(card);
    }
}

class Player {
    constructor() {
        this.hands = [[]];
        this.currentHand = 0; // for splits
        this.numHands = 1;
        this.double = false;
    }
    getCurrentHand() {
        return this.hands[this.currentHand];
    }

    hit(card) {
        this.getCurrentHand().push(card);
        return this.hands;
      }
    //other functions like split() here, omitting for clarity.
```

Here is where my app starts up. I make my `players` and `setPlayers`. All of this works as expected, it initializes the state it needs, and when everything is ready it deals out the cards. I see the cards on screen how I want. I'll place my `Hands` component at the end so this isn't all floating code, but it isn't relevant to my question I don't think.

```
export default function App() {

  const [deck, setDeck] = useState(initDeck());
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState(new Players(numPlayers));

  useEffect(() => {
    deal(deck, count, setCount, players, setPlayers);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(players);
  }, [players])
}
```

**Here's where my question is:** I have gone through a bunch of different ways, in App, how to use `setPlayers()`. I'm not going to post all my attempts, but all the results were either the `useEffect` hook not executing on change, or saying something is not a function when I've used it prior. **It's somehow copying the object wrong and losing it's ability to call any function...**

Here's my `hit` function in App, where I am dealing with my `const [players, setPlayers] = useState(new Players(numPlayers));` I created at the beginning.

I haven't run into any problems with `setCount` because it's just a simple integer.

```
function hit(deck, count, setCount, players, setPlayers) {
  let card = deck.pop();
  setCount(incrementCardCount(card, count));
  players.hit(card);
  setPlayers({...players}); // this updates with the useEffect([players]). Others don't. 
}
```

I've also tried weird stuff like `let newPlayers = players` at the beginning of the function, and then trying `setPlayers(newPlayers)`, but none of these weird solutions I'm trying fix the problem at hand. It feels like I'm totally missing something fundamental to React, or `useEffect` or `useState` on objects or *something*

`Hands` component just to put it here, not relevant to question really. It loops through my `Players` and displays their cards on screen where I want.

```
return (
<View key={styles.playerHands}>
    {props.players.players.map((player, i) =>
        <View key={`player-${i}`} style={styles.player}>
            {player.hands.map((cards, j) =>
                <View key={`player-${i}-${j}`} style={styles.hand}>
                    {cards.map((card, k) =>
                        <Image key={`player-${i}-${j}-${k}`} style={createCardOverlap(k, j)} resizeMode={'contain'} source={displayCard(card)} />
                    )}
                </View>
            )}
        </View>
    )}
</View>
)
```

Hopefully this is well enough explained, to reiterate I'm trying to understand how to use `setPlayers()` on my `Players` obj. I'm confused how doing this `setPlayers({...players});` totally rips away its ability to call any of its functions, and I don't know how to work around the obvious `setPlayers(players)` after I call some functions on `player` to update its state.

Am I doing this correctly, because it feels like I am missing something. All of the updating state happens in App, my `Players` obj just normally updates its internal state.

Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest not using a class inside `useState` at all.

Comment: Gotcha. So what's the best way to go about this? I'm definitely missing some fundamental design paradigm here. I suppose just a bunch of separate `useState` for the properties I have in my `Players` class currently, it just felt very cumbersome to deal with a TRIPLE nested array in that way. A list of players, each of which has a nested array for the multiple hands they can have. I guess your response is going to be, yeah just deal with that directly instead of abstracting it out to the class?

Is it not a good idea to use an object to track state, just don't put functions in there? 

TY

Answer (score 0):

`setPlayers({...players});` creates a new plain object and fills it in with the own public data properties of `players`. It does **not** create a `Players` instance; the plain object doesn't have the correct prototype and wasn't initialized by the `Player` constructor. To do that, you need to call `new Players`.

I've found that I rarely use objects in state that aren't just plain objects (for which spread works), but sometimes it's handy. If you want to use `Players`, you need to update `Players` to provide a way of creating a new `Players` object with the necessary changes.

FWIW, I wouldn't have a `Players` class, it doesn't seem to offer much of anything. I'd just have a `Players` array and hold the `currentPlayer` in state. Then have `Player.prototype.hit` return a new, updated `Player` object. Since [objects in state must not be directly modified](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly), you'd probably want to write `Player` using immutable methodology (methods don't modify the state of the object, they return a new object with the updated state).

---

As a side note, it looks like `hit` is breaking that "[do not modify state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)" rule in a couple of ways:

- Calling `pop` on `deck` directly modifies the state of `deck`.
- Calling `hit` on `this.players[this.currentPlayer]` (inside `Players.prototype.hit`) directly modifies the player object that's inside `Players`.

Comment: Doesn't using `setPlayers(new Players(...))` undermine the reason for using a class?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Not in my view, no. I think it depends a lot on the use case. I usually use plain objects for React state, but I have had cases where I wanted a more complex one.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I ultimately decided on the class because my my list of players comes down to a triple nested array... an array of players, and each player has a nested array of hands, because a single player can have multiple hands after they split. So for that complexity I decided on the class, I can see myself sticking with the class (or really just glorified JSON) and putting the functions not within the class... I definitely don't know good practice for this lol, it feels super bad what I' m doing tho

Comment: @Suttenburger - Yeah, sometimes they can help with complexity, other times they add to it. But if you're using classes for things in React state, generally you're best off writing them as immutables. (Side note: Not glorified JSON, because they aren't strings -- JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. :-) )

Comment: Thank you, it's well late tonight so I'll look into this further tomorrow. Seems it's just not at all worth the effort, nor is it "react-ey" to have classes with functions. Should just be data.

Does that mean, just for organizations sake, should these functions just be in `App.js`? feels ugly since I'll end up having so many functions like that in `App`.

I clearly come from an OOP background, and it shows, so I'm wondering how to break these habits.